# The prefered way of replacing response in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I need to intercept a REST operation in Spring MVC and return random data. What is the prefered way to do it? Should I use interceptor, advice, controler advice or something else?

Thank you!

Comment: there is no one answer to this. You can use all three. but based on your requirement you have to choose. Controller Advices are triggered only when there is an exception.

Comment: @pvpkiran The thing is that I need not to call the original handler. And as far as I see I can do it with around advice only. Am I right?

Comment: yes you can do this with around advice